# Is there a way to possibly put a case statement in the from clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I'm trying to select from different locations depending on a certain aspect. Is it possible to put a `CASE` statement in the `FROM` clause?

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
FROM (Case WHEN @location = 'location A' THEN stockA 
WHEN @location = 'location B' then stockB end) ss
```

StockA is what I would be pulling it from if I wasn't selecting multiple locations. SS is the alias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Here is a sort-of-close method:

```
select ab.*
from ((select a.*
       from stockA a
       where @location = 'location A'
      ) union all
      (select b.*
       from stockB b
       where @location = 'location B'
      )
     ) ab
```

Comment: This part `where @location = 'location A'` looking bit strange to me. Will it work actually? I mean will it resolve parameter to actual column name? Not sure. AFAIK, `where col = @param`

Comment: @Rahul . . . You seem confused.  The `where` clause is comparing a variable to a literal value.  That is all.  There are no columns involved here.